# If $P(A) = 0.37$, $(\text{not }A \cup ) = 0.22$, and $P(B) = 0.54$, compute $P(A\cup B)$.

Tags: probability

I could use help with this question.

> If $P(A) = 0.37$, $(\text{not }A \cup ) = 0.22$, and $P(B) = 0.54$, compute $P(A\cup B)$.

So $P(\text{not }A \cap B)$ is the probability of just $B$ occurring.

Which means $P(A\text{ and }B) = .54-.22 = .32$
$P(A\cup B) = P(A)-P(A \text{ and }B) + P(B)-P(A \text{ and } B) = .05+.22=.27$.

So $P(A\cup B)$ should be $.27$, right?

Something in my math seems off, but not sure where.

Comment: Please note that $P({A}\cup{B})$ couldn't possibly be smaller than $P(A)$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- $P({A}\cup{B})=P(A)+P(B)-\color\red{P({A}\cap{B})}$
- $\color\red{P({A}\cap{B})}=P(B)-P(\neg{A}\cap{B})$